# woocomerce add to cart button with quantity field

Tags: woocommerce

Help needed

How to set button with quantity field in content-single-product.php page...

do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item');

sets the field and button, but quantity doesnt changes in cart. ADD TO CART button sets only 1 item.

Answer (score 0):

For custom single product page you should do `do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary')` instead of `do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item')`

`do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary')`  will allow user to select no of product he/she would like to buy.